# JS set font color

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game in JavaScript and I want to change te text color.

This is a part of the code:

```
if (game.active) {
    this.damageCountry(otherLost, country);
}
battle.sendMessage("You have failed to " +     
game.normalizeCountryName(country) + " conquer", 
    "<em>" + game.normalizeCountryName(country) + "'s losses: </em>"+ 
     Math.round(otherLost).commafy() + "</br><em>your losses: </em>" + 
     Math.round(lost).commafy());
```

I want to change the text color of battle.sendMessage.

```
this.sendMessage    =   function(title, message){
    $(".battle").show();
    $(".battle>h1").first().html(title);
    $(".battle>p").first().html(message);
    this.title      =   title;
    this.message    =   message;
```

Comment: almost everything in the if.

Comment: @Sebas We don't know what you want to change the text color of

Comment: you mean this? this.sendMessage  = function(title, message){
  $(".top-message").show();
  $(".top-message>h1").first().html(title);
  $(".top-message>p").first().html(message);
  this.title   = title;
  this.message  = message;

Comment: @vihan1086 I want to change the color of battle.sendMessage

Comment: @Sebas can we see the code of `battle.sendMessage`

Comment: @Sebas Added my answer, is that what you want?

Comment: This is a simple css question. If you posted the relevant part of the html it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.sendMessage    =   function(title, message){
    $(".top-message").show();
    $(".top-message>h1").first().html(title).css('color', 'red');
    $(".top-message>p").first().html(message).css('color', 'red');
    this.title      =   title;
    this.message    =   message;
```

This will make the `font-color` red. Change as you would like.

---

This uses **jQuery** `$.fn.css()` learn more [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

---

Change the following:

```
battle.sendMessage("You have failed to <span style=\"color:red\">" +     
    game.normalizeCountryName(country) + "</span> conquer", 
    "<em>" + game.normalizeCountryName(country) + "'s losses: </em>"+ 
     Math.round(otherLost).commafy() + "</br><em>your losses: </em>" + 
     Math.round(lost).commafy());
```

Add:

```
"<span style=\"color: YOUR_COLOR;\">Text...</span>"
```

Comment: And if i want use multible colors for different lines?

Comment: @Sebas where it says `'red'` change the color. You can use different colors for different lines. I'll update my answer now

Comment: and if i want to give " game.normalizeCountryName(country)" a color? It shows a country.

Comment: @Sebas I made it red, change the color as you wish

Comment: If I use the span on game.normalizeCountryName(country) the game isnt working anymore.

Comment: @Sebas you can use another element, try `font`